# c# stringbuilder performance

Tags: c#, performance, stringbuilder

I have a for-loop with around 50k iterations.
is it more efficient to do it like this:

```
Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
for(int i = 0; i<50000; i++)
   {
      sb.Clear();
      sb.Append("test") //Add everytime 9 different string even from parameters
      string s = sb.ToString();
}
```

or it is more efficient to do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<50000; i++)
{
   Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
   sb.Append("..."); //the same like above
   string s = sb.ToString();
}
```

So my question is: Is it faster to reinitialize the Stringbuilder in every loop or is it a better way to use the `Stringbuilder.Clear()` function?
Or is it in my case of 9 different values in the string even better to concenate the strings?

Best Regards!

Comment: Did you measure both approaches?

Comment: Why reinitialize the String builder? Do you know what the difference is between a String and Stringbuilder?

Comment: Try it out with BenchmarkDotNet: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: It is not only about StringBuilder performance. The second approach creates more work for the GC.

Comment: How many strings do you append to the StringBuilder before clearing it. For a lower number of appends it is better to use the traditional approach of string concat.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? Memory? Speed? CPU load? Code maintenance?

Comment: You talk about parameters. Is this code being used to generate a prepared statement?

Comment: Why are you even using StringBuilder if you are not concatenating anything? In both examples you clear it after exactly one use

Comment: Check the reference source for Clear:
[link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,12bafac7fd9481fd,references)
You will notice that it merely sets the Length to 0 but it does not dispose allocated buffers. [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,7d7729bd88adac53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach should be more performant, since it does (at least) 2x less 
allocations. One `string` instance will be allocated per iteration in any case, but there is no need to instantiate a new `StringBuilder` each time.

In practice, the second approach will have even more allocations per iteration, unless you specify the initial capacity manually (and specify a large enough capacity). Otherwise the `StringBuilder` might have to allocate several additional chunks (doubling its capacity each time).

Since calling `StringBuilder.Clear()` simply resets the current length, chunks that are already allocated are not trimmed/collected by `Clear()`, so the next iteration will already have the buffer prepared, and "probably" of the right size.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code :

- First loop takes `1 ms`
- Second loop takes `3 ms`